# MySQL seeks the maximum query is very slow（With the subquery）

Tags: mysql

```
        select a.*
    from  tb_szjc_data a
    where   deviceSN= '000'
    and createtime=(select max(createtime)
        from  tb_szjc_data
        where   deviceSN= '000')
```

```
    select a.*
        from  tb_szjc_data a
        where   
         createtime=(select max(createtime)
            from  tb_szjc_data
            where   deviceSN= a.deviceSN) and a.deviceSN= '000'
```

Why is the first SQL query is very fast?  MySQL version is 5.7

```
deviceSN= '000' Data 2W
```

Answer (score 0):

Even faster

```
SELECT *
    FROM tb_szjc_data
    WHERE deviceSN = '000'
    ORDER BY createtime DESC
    LIMIT 1
```

if you also have

```
INDEX(deviceSN, createtime)
```

As for "why" one is faster than the other, we need to see `SHOW CREATE TABLE`, especially the indexes.